# Manipulating variables at compile time with C++

Tags: c++, variables, c++11

Since I lost track of the C++11 and C++14 (not out yet I suppose) changes, I was wondering if the following is possible in C++ or if there is any plan to make something like this working: I need a way to query a class or a function whether it uses a variable or not. If not, I should be able to add a variable used in a higher scope (either from a caller function or some code that instantiates that class).

I can do all this at runtime but it has a performance penalty I can't afford. Writing my own compiler sounds heavy.

Comment: In short: No, such isn't available.

Comment: It might be useful if you explain why you're trying to do this as we may be able to offer alternative solutions.

Comment: I want to write my own framework where a user can supply a program (whatever that is, a function, a class..) and I schedule/call/modify those according to the algorithms of my framework. The purpose is to better schedule/time/manage the resources.

Comment: Please define "A class or function *uses* a variable". And of course your motivation behind this so we understand *what* you are trying to achieve as compared to *how* you wish to do it.

Comment: @ArneMertz I need some executable code user-provided which may or may not use a variable. And I need some type of "scope-overriding" mechanism. I haven't decided if that code should be in a class or function, it just needs to be executable and user-provided.

Comment: Create a library for them to link against and define your own interface for them to derive from, that's as close as you're going to get (if I've understood the question properly). Unless you use some kinda of macro magic...

Comment: Despite your responses, it is still too vague what you're trying to do and what you're looking for. Some code or examples would help.

Comment: This is basically impossible because of the side-effects and aliasing that can happen in C++. Unless you introduce new restricting constructs that is.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution to your real problem is NOT a variable which you somehow query.

I'd personally use a template which the user may or may not instantiate. That's quite easy to discover. It's also an existing mechanism which works in C++98, 03 11 and 14.

Remember that under the ordinary C++ compilation model, you can't query at **your** compile time whether another function **will** use a variable when it is compiled. That would take a time machine.

Comment: I'm curious, can you expand on this template instantiation mechanism? Do you mean using a template which might be instantiated or not as a variable into the user's code or what?

Comment: @DavidKernin: Yup, the library defines a `template <typename T> class Foo` and the user defines a variable, instantiating `Foo` while doing so. Obviously you can't figure out at compile time if any function uses a specific `int`. Only the linker knows.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a dynamic framework (allowing you to change application behavior from the outside, based on RTTI). (exactly what you are asking is a bit vague).

Such behavior is not offered by the C++ compiler directly, but can be implemented using either an existing C++ framework, or custom code.

You can write an application using Microsoft COM technology (under Windows), or Mozilla XPCOM (cross-platform) technology for implementing dynamic feature support (through the IUnknown interface) but it requires that you define your own (custom) interfaces for that and the effort is non-trivial.

You can also go with a custom code library. I would prefer this, but it depends on the effort you can put into this and other limits imposed by your project (time constraints, budget, etc).